# How to initialize this plugin inside my HTML doc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm trying to initialize this plugin in different ways, inside my HTML document, but it seems isn't working...

I attached a picture of the Usage documentation, and this is the link of the plugin: https://unpkg.com/darkreader.
I'm using javascript for that, and not typeScript.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXi4S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here you haven't mentioned how you're including plugin in HTML document, So try to add jquery first and after that include this script like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js> 
         </script>
         <script src="/scripts/darkreader.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the end of my HTML file:

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Google LogIn Client -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- DarkReader Dark theme plugin -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/darkreader@4.7.15/darkreader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      import {
          enable as enableDarkMode,
          disable as disableDarkMode,
      } from 'darkreader';

      enableDarkMode({
          brightness: 100,
          contrast: 90,
          sepia: 10,
      });
    </script>
```

I tried to initialize the plugin, but still not working...